# How to embed a part/element of a page

Tags: html, embed

I have created a test on a page and i need to embed it on a other page:
https://mmi.kaige.nl/test/studie-matchmaker/

The test needs to be visible on an other page. Please your help

I have tried to embed it with the following code, but this also embeds the menu...

```
<iframe src=".post-1301 .post-content" width="100%" height="100%">
    <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
    <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
</iframe>
```

Would be great if i could embed the test on a page including the button that leads to the result.

Comment: `src=".post-1301 .post-content"`, I don't think that is a valid file

Comment: Is the "other page" same domain? If CORS is set up properly, you can use CSS to be applied inside your IFRAME.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The other page is the same domain, i also tried src="/test/studie-matchmaker/"

This worked but included the main menu inside the embeded part.

Answer (score 0):

If I think I know what you are trying to ask : 
You should add or a div element or a table element like :

```html
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
  <iframe src=".post-1301 .post-content" width="100%" height="100%">
        <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
        <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
  </iframe>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<div>
  <iframe src=".post-1301 .post-content" width="100%" height="100%">
        <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
        <span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
  </iframe>
</div>
```